# How to get late minutes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column A - populated by a form (time stamp) - user makes a punch by a form

Column D has a target Date
Column E has a target hour (when he must have reached)

I want to display his late minutes (if he is late - compared to target date and hour)

In column F, I entered formula `=late(A7,D7,E7)`

But, it is not working correctly

```
function late(rep,asdt,asti) {
  var asnd=new Date(asdt.getFullYear(),asdt.getMonth(),asdt.getDate(),asti);
  //var nextday = new Date(today.getTime()+(10*3600*1000)); //10 hours from now
  //var asnd=new Date(asdt.getTime() + (asti*60*60*1000));
  if (rep.getTime() > asnd.getTime()){
    return ((rep.getTime()-asnd.getTime())/(60*60*1000));
  } else {  return 0  }
}
```

It is showing wrong minutes

and it is showing late minutes even when he is not late.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You are very close!

- The issue is with the conversion from milliseconds to minutes.

If you want to get the difference in minutes you need to use `60*1000`:

[image]

Your code gets the difference in hours. I am not sure why the results are not even difference in hours, <del>but my guess would be that you haven't refreshed the custom formula</del>.

**Update:**

After discussion with the OP, the second issue was that the timezones between the spreadsheet and the script were different. The OP changed the timezone of the script to match the timezone of the spreadsheet and the code suggested in this answer worked.

### Solution:

This:

```
function late(rep,asdt,asti) {
  var asnd=new Date(asdt.getFullYear(),asdt.getMonth(),asdt.getDate(),asti);
  if (rep.getTime() > asnd.getTime()){
    return ((rep.getTime()-asnd.getTime())/(60*1000));
  } else {  return 0  }
}
```

gives me the correct difference in minutes according to my data:

[image]

**Please Note:**

Custom functions / formulas are not refreshed in the same way as built-in google sheets formula. You need to change the value of at least one of the arguments in the custom function in order to update it. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) you can find more details about custom functions.

Comment: I found the problem and corrected it. Still it is not working. I'm sharing the sheet with edit rights. The target date and hour comes from another sheet by a query and is linked by ticket number by an arrayformula. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wQAOk4979ygLCXDNecx5daynAW38rNVPK2yE4H6hyzk/edit#gid=1534738327

Comment: @arulselvan I found the issue. Your spreadsheet has the timezone of India, but your script has a timezone of GMT-5. The timezones should be identical. Solution: switch to the legacy editor then go to File => Project properties and change the time zone to GMT+5:30 India Standard Time.

Comment: ---I was totally puzzled. I could never have guessed it !!! Thanks a lot

Comment: @arulselvan glad it was helpful to you.